# Where does the Win10 Toast Notification snoozed data reside?

Tags: windows-10, action-center

I just created a powershell script to show a toast notification with a Snooze button with time options. This is what I have problems with:

[Toast Notification with Snooze option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pphga.jpg)

Every time I execute the script I want to check if there is a previous snoozed notification and if there is the scrip will exit not showing a new notification.

Does anyone knows where does the snoozed notifications data resides? I tried looking on the registry but no luck, I'm sure there has to be some place where it holds the notification until the snooze time finishes to show it again in the Action Center.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same question and found the answer here:

$toastNotifier = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($appId)
$toastNotifier.getScheduledToastNotifications()

This will show you a list of snoozed notifications.

Sourced from https://adminsccm.com/2019/06/24/dismiss-a-snoozed-toast-notification-before-it-shows-again/